# What race is Sauron and was he involved in the creation of the rings of power?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, sauron, tolkiens-legendarium

Okay, from my understanding, the Elves were the ones who made the Rings of Power, but who specifically made them? Were they just created by blacksmiths or was Sauron involved in their creation too?

His aim was to rule all of Middle Earth (assumedly) with his One Ring, but the Elves (and possibly the Dwarves) seemed to have thwarted his attempts to control them. So would that hint that he is an Elf, or perhaps a Dark Elf?

Comment: See also our earlier question http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12829 whose answers explain who forged all the other Rings of Power.

Comment: -1 For failing to do any kind of research, either watching the intro for the movies or reading the book. Or googling.

Comment: @AndresF. - The movies do not explain that he was Maia...

Comment: Oh this is adorable.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Sauron was a fallen **Maia**. His race was **Ainur**.

> There was Eru, the One, who in Arda is called Ilúvatar; and he made
> first the Ainur, the Holy Ones, that were the offspring of his
> thought...
> <sub>-- First words of the Ainulindalë</sub>

> They were the primordial spirits, who existed with Ilúvatar, and with
> him created the world through The Ainulindalë, The Music of the Ainur.
> After the creation of Arda, many of the Ainur descended into it to
> guide and order its growth; of these there were fifteen more powerful
> than the rest.
> <sub>-- LotR Fandom Wiki, https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Ainur</sub>

> Before the creation of Ea, Sauron was one of the countless lesser
> Ainur spirits created by Eru Iluvatar, known as the Maia. At this time
> he was known as Mairon the Admirable, and partook in the Ainulindale,
> or Music of the Ainur. However, unlike many other spirits, Mairon did
> not align himself with Melkor upon the introduction of his discord
> themes, and thus, did not initially fall under his sway.
> <sub>-- Super Smash Bros. Fanfic Wiki, https://ssb-tourney.fandom.com/wiki/Sauron</sub>

The Rings of Power were twenty magical rings forged in the Second Age, intended by Sauron to seduce the rulers of Middle-earth to evil. **Nineteen of these rings were made by the elven-smiths of Eregion, led by Celebrimbor.** The **One Ring** was forged by Sauron himself.

Comment: Other Maiar: the Wizards (Saruman, Gandalf, Radagast) and the Balrog(s)

Comment: To be exact, Sauron took on a pleasant appearance and instructed Celebrimbor and the elven-smiths in how to make rings of power. The first 16 rings were made with Sauron's assistance. The three elven-rings were made by the elves alone, and so they were the least tainted by Sauron's evil.

Comment: The Three themselves were not tainted at all, but still *subject* to the One.

Comment: @Dennis_E And the two Blue wizards (I know they were named in the letters but I can't recall the names immediately). I'm pretty sure there are others too but I'm in a state where I'm not trusting my judgement so I won't say there are.

Comment: There were more rings in early versions of LotR -  Gandalf tells Bingo Bolger-Baggins ( precursor to Frodo) about "dozens".

Answer (score 12):

Sauron's race is Maia.

> Among those of his servants that have names the greatest was that spirit whom the Eldar called Sauron, or Gorthaur the Cruel. In his beginning he was of the Maiar of Aulë, and he remained mighty in the lore of that people. In all the deeds of Melkor the Morgoth upon Arda, in his vast works and in the deceits of his cunning, Sauron had a part...

-- Ainulindalë - Of the Enemies

Sauron was originally Melkor's lieutenant, and a lesser being:

> And Melkor made also a fortress and armoury not far from the north-western shores of the sea, to resist any assault that might come from Aman. That stronghold was commanded by *Sauron, lieutenant of Melkor*...

-- Quenta Silmarillion - Chapter 3 - Of the Coming of the Elves and the Captivity of Melkor

The Maiar are lesser Ainur:

> With the Valar came other spirits whose being also began before the World, of the same order as the Valar but of less degree. These are the Maiar, the people of the Valar, and their servants and helpers.

-- Ainulindalë - Of the Maiar

Sauron created the One Ring himself, in order to gain control over the wearers of all the other rings.

> Now the Elves made many rings; but secretly Sauron made One Ring to rule all the others...

Because he put so much of his own power into the Ring, its destruction was essential to defeating him:

> And much of the strength and will of Sauron passed into that One Ring; for the power of the Elven-rings was very great, and that which should govern them must be a thing of surpassing potency...

Answer (score -3):

Sauron is an Ainu. Other Ainu include:

- The Valar who are basically the gods and do nothing throughout LOTR.
- The Istari, or Wizards, who were sent by the Valar to fight Sauron. They gave up their shapeshifting and most of their magic.
- The Valaraukar, or Balrogs, who were minions of Morgoth.
  Morgoth, the first Dark Lord, originally the most powerful of the Valar, but lost his power because he used it for evil. This is why all the Dark Lords have to rely on armies. They have lost all of their magic. Sauron got around this via his ring, but without it he was so weak he couldn't even maintain a physical form.
- The Sun, which is actually a giant floating mango carried by a powerful Ainu.
- The Moon, which is a giant flower carried by a different Ainu who has a crush on the first Ainu.
- Aragorn, who is 99% human, .999% elf, and .0001% Ainu.
- Elrond, who is 56.25% elf, 37.5%% human, and 6.25% Ainu.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! What's your source for all this information?

Comment: Hi Niser, you may want to take the [tour]. As F1Krazy pointed out, your answer may get voted down if you down cite sources.